# Search meta key in object and get value

Tags: php, object

I did a var_dump of my current order in Woocommerce. The output is a big object of data: https://snippi.com/s/rftgioq

Somewhere in this object is the key _enviso_order_id and _enviso_order_number. Is it somehow possible to do a "search" in the object and get the corresponding values.

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // this gets the data from the current order
var_dump($order); // dump from the data. Full example: https://snippi.com/s/rftgioq
```

I've tried this to get the _enviso_order_id

```
$enviso_id = $order->_enviso_order_id;
echo $enviso_id;
```

But it's empty.

Comment: have a look at the [docs](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/wc_get_order) for ways to parse the object

Comment: What is the output when you `var_dump($order->get_data());`?

Comment: @RJK This is the output: https://snippi.com/s/bv1yrr0

Comment: @Dennis Would you be able to do another one using `var_export`? This would make it easier to debug an array of this size.

Comment: @Dennis Looking at the original dump, try this, `$data = $order->get_data(); $data['meta_data'][8]->_enviso_order_id`

Comment: @RJK thanks for helping my out with this. Your solution with $date['meta_data'][8]->_enviso_order_id doesn't work. It prints nothing. This is the output of var_export: https://snippi.com/s/3qq8hwn

Comment: @Dennis Just to clarify the `$data` variable is named correctly in your code? as you are using `$date` as shown above, unless its a typo

Comment: @Dennis Having another look at the data dump, it looks like the metadata is stored as JSON under the key 'value', can you do the following: `$data = $order->get_data(); var_export($data['meta_data'][8]->value);`?

Comment: @RJK sorry $date was a typo in stackoverflow. It's not in my code. I've did var_export($data['meta_data'][8]->value); and it prints NULL.

Comment: @Dennis I have moved this to a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226923/discussion-between-rjk-and-dennis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing the issue with OP (which can be found [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226923/discussion-between-rjk-and-dennis)), the following answered the question:

```
$value = $order->get_meta_data()[8]->get_data()['value'];
$metadata = json_decode($value);
$enviso_id = $metadata[0]->_enviso_order_id;

echo $enviso_id;
```

The issue with this is that the 'enviso' metadata may not always be stored in the 8th element of the array, which will produce errors if using the code sample above.

The array returned from `get_data()` also includes a key called `key`, which indicates what the metadata relates to (in this case its '_enviso_order_info'), we can use this to create a helper function to extract the 'enviso' metadata from the order:

```
function get_enviso_metadata($order) {
    $metadatas = $order->get_meta_data();
    
    foreach($metadatas as $metadata) {
        $data = $metadata->get_data();
        
        if($data['key'] == '_enviso_order_info') {
            return json_decode($data['value'], true)[0];
        }
    }
    
    return [];
}
```

Usage example:

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$envisoMetadata = get_enviso_metadata($order);

echo $envisoMetadata['_enviso_order_id'];
```

As I don't have access to the development environment I have no way of testing this, but after discussing it with OP, I think it should work.

Comment: Thank you ! Works like a charm/